# How to let CefSharp WinForms 32 bit run on Windows 64 bit?

Tags: chromium, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have downloaded the CefSharp 71.0.0-pre01 Source code from the official release,  and built it successfully by VS 2015 on my Windows 7 Ultimate x64.

I have checked all x86 and x64 release build, and the project built all 22 items successfully includes the example exe.

The WinForm Example folder has 2 output in the bin, the x64 release can run well on my Win7 x64, but the x86 (32 bit) release doesn't work. Once I run the "CefSharp.WinForms.Example.exe", it shows

```
CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess has stopped working
```

When I click to check issue details, it shows:

```
Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name: CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess.exe
```

But when I run the x86 release on the Win7 32bit machine, it works well.

I wanted to build an AnyCPU version but the project doesn't support AnyCPU, then I assumed the x86/32bit should work on both 64/32 machines. Is it possible to do that?

Comment: Using the `71.0.0-pre01` packages from `Nuget.org` is the only supported option. `AnyCPU` is possible, see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample/tree/demo/anycpu for a working example.

Comment: I have tried to debug by VS while it is showing the error, the VS shows - Failed to load file or assembly "CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess, Version=49.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138" or one of its dependencies. Strong name verification failed.

Comment: Download and test with the `MinimalExample`, make sure that works to start with.

Comment: Very strange...Here is the testing result: The x86 version could run all Win7/Win8/Win10 32/64 bit PCs, except my PC, Win7 x64. I have uninstalled all VC Redists and reinstalled, nothing changed. I don't know why.

Comment: What antivirus do you have?

Comment: I have shut down all antivirus products

Comment: Are you using the `MinimalExample` or a custom build from source? I really don't have enough information to make any suggestions, specially as it's working on other machines.

Answer (score 0):

A case I've experienced is setting `max_old_space_size` to a large value which causes render subprocess to crash on startup when running in `32bit` mode. Removing this option resolved the issue for me.